# C++ функция Split. Оптимизация

Tags: c++, c

Написал вот такие две функции для нахождения длины строки и разбиение ее на лексемы. Как можно еще оптимизировать данный код, не используя библиотечных функций?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int length(char *array)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*array++) i++;

    return i;
}

char **split(char *text, char delim)
{
    int words = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<length(text); i++)
        if(text[i] == delim) words++;

    char **result = new char*[words];

    for(int i=0; i<words; i++)
        result[i] = new char[length(text)];

    int j = 0, t = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<words; i++)
    {
        while(text[j] != delim && text[j] != '\0') result[i][t++] = text[j++];

        j++;
        t = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char *text = "audi mersedez reno lambo";

    char **result = split(text, ' ');

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        cout << result[i] << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        delete result[i];
    delete [] result;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ну для начала вынести получение длины из цикла `for(int i=0; i<length(text); i++)` вы же на каждой итерации циула вызываете получение длины строки и всю ее пробегаете заново. ну и позже опять length используете...

Comment: И вообще все странно. зачем нужны 3 цикла. в одном цикле выделяете очередной элемент result, и копируете в него пока лексема не закончилась (раз уж вы все равно выделяете блоки на всю длину строки). как закончилась, выделяете следующий элемент и копируете уже в него. тогда вы все сделаете вообще за 1 проход строки. А вообще если важна скорость то принято вообще ничего не копировать а делать просто массив с указателями на подстроки внутри той же строки и запоминать длину участков

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Функция определения длины строки.

Выполняет на каждой итерации цикла две операции инкремента, указателя на строку и переменной, хранящей длину строки.
Эффективней будет перед циклом запомнить значение указателя на строку, в цикле пробежаться до нулеваого символа, увеличивая указатель, а вернуть разницу между адресом нулевого символа и адресом первого символа строки.

```
int length(char *array){
    char *start=array;
    while (*array++);

    return array-start-1;
}
```

### Функция split.

При определении количества слов, вы в условии цикла

```
for(int i=0; i<length(text); i++)
    if(text[i] == delim) words++;
```

вызываете функцию length ровно столько раз, сколько символов в строке text. И на каждом вызове в функции length происходит выполнение цикла по всей строке, для определения нулевого символа.
Стоит, или вынести определение длины строки из цикла, создав отдельную переменную

```
int len = length(text);
for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
```

или можно определить переменную длины прямо в цикле, но перенести это определение в блок инициализации цикла

```
for(int i=0, len = length(text); i<len; i++)
```

в этом же цикле (как и во всяком подобном, у вас их еще два далее в функции split) эффективней использовать для изменения счетчика не пост, а пред инкремент. Дело в том,
что пост инкремент сохраняет начальное значение переменной, увеличивает ее и возвращает начальное значение. На это тратится время.

```
for(int i=0, len = length(text); i<len; ++i)
```

тоже самое можно применить и к переменной words

```
if(text[i] == delim) ++words;
```

и так же можно делать для всех инкрементов в циклах

Все, что касается функции length справедливо и для цикла

```
for(int i=0; i<words; i++)
    result[i] = new char[length(text)];
```

в котором вы так же многократно вызываете length. И так как длина строки используется в двух циклах, то все же лучше определить в самом начале переменную длины строки

```
int len = length(text);
```

и использовать это значение, когда необходимо.

Так же последние два цикла, можно объединить, потому что после выделения памяти под слово его сразу же можно туда копировать из исходной строки.

```
int j = 0; 
for(int i=0; i<words; ++i){
    result[i] = new char[len];
    int t = 0;
    while(text[j] != delim && text[j] != '\0') result[i][t++] = text[j++];
    j++;
}
```

Так же примем сразу, что split разбивает именно не константные строки, потому что для константных строк реализация, по идее, должна быть совершенно другой.
Ну и использование динамической памяти в таком виде с высокой долей вероятности неудобно и приведет в итоге к ошибкам. Но, если вам важно получить на выходе именно такую структуру, то и пусть.
Функцию main рассматривать не будем. Как и передачу функции пустой строки. В итоге получается так

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int length(char *array){
    char *start=array;
    while (*array++);

    return array-start-1;
}

char **split(char *text, char delim)
{
    int words = 1;
    int len = length(text);

    for(int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        if(text[i] == delim) ++words;

    char **result = new char*[words];

    int j = 0; 
    for(int i=0; i<words; ++i){
        result[i] = new char[len];
        int t = 0;
        while(text[j] != delim && text[j] != '\0') result[i][t++] = text[j++];
        j++;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
   char *text = "audi mersedez reno lambo";

    char **result = split(text, ' ');

    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        cout << result[i] << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        delete result[i];
    delete [] result;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ни в цикле для i, ни для words результат выполнения никуда не возвращается, а просто значение переменной увеличивается, поэтому разницы между пре- и пост-инкрементом в этих случаях нет.

Comment: Возможно, что для int оптимизатор сделает в обоих случаях одинаковый код, но для не встроенных типов очень может быть, что и нет. Поэтому, имхо, лучше в подобных случаях использовать прединкремент и не давать повода  компилятору решать как лучше.

Comment: Просто для целого числа - не стоит. Компилятор если захочет, все равно сделает как ему виднее)